# A way to determine if a body accelerates or loses speed at a certain time

Tags: kinematics, vectors

With given vectors for acceleration and velocity, is there a way to determine if a body accelerates or decelerates at a certain time-interval? Can this be determined, for instance, by simply observing the vectors?

Comment: Hint: $d|v|^2/dt=\lim_{\delta t\to 0}[(v+a\delta t)^2-v^2]/\delta t$

Answer (score 0):

> With given vectors for acceleration and velocity, is there a way to determine if a body accelerates or decelerates at a certain time-interval?

Given the velocity vectors of a (specific) body (with respect to specific members of a suitable reference system) throughout a trial, in particular the velocity vectors $\mathbf v_{\text{initial}}$ at the beginning of the trial and $\mathbf v_{\text{final}}$ at the end of the trial, then

- the body is said to have "gained speed" (on average, over the course of the trial) if $\| \mathbf v_{\text{final}} \| \gt \|  \mathbf v_{\text{initial}} \|$,
  where the double bars denote the magnitude ([norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space)) of the vector; and
- the body is said to have "lost speed" (on average, over the course of the trial) if $\| \mathbf v_{\text{final}} \| \lt \| \mathbf v_{\text{initial}} \|.$

> Can this be determined, for instance, by simply observing the vectors?

No, not merely "*by observing*". Instead, the magnitudes of vectors, in comparison to each other, are to be **measured**; i.e. derived from observational data, to obtain unambiguous commensurate values.